# От чего защищают методы типа secure_filename?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, файлы, сервер, безопасность

Многие веб-фреймворки предлагают при сохранении файла пользователя на сервере проверять его имя и контент для защиты. Допустим, мой сервер только читает этот файл и пишет его размер клиенту. Если не использовать никакой защиты, а сохранять файл как есть, чего конкретно надо опасаться? Ведь файл никак не исполняется, а если имя слишком длинное, то просто будет `OSError` при открытии в `Python` и т.п.. Нужна ли защита в таком случае?

Пример метода https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename

Comment: Если имя файла будет что-то вроде `../manage.py` или `../../../../var/www/index.html` то он сохранится совершенно не туда, куда вы планировали

Comment: Собственно, по вашей же ссылке в документации написано ровно о том же самом с примерами... Неужели всё равно непонятно?

Comment: @andreymal то есть таким способом можно переписать уже исполняемый файл своим? И не будет никакой ошибки от питона? В том что просто сохранится в каком-то месте != текущей директории не вижу проблемы, прочитается потом по тому же пути ведь

Comment: Получится перезаписать любой файл, к которому есть доступ на запись. А если вы случайно оказались достаточно недальновидны и запустили веб-сервер под пользователем root, то получится перезаписать вообще абсолютно любой системный файл... Например, запись в файл `../../../../../dev/sda` убьёт ваш жёсткий диск

Comment: @andreymal а как пользователь может создать файл с `/` в названии?

Comment: А его не нужно создавать, достаточно в запросе вручную прописать HTTP-заголовок или поле формы с любым желаемым именем

Comment: @andreymal ладно, убедили, серьезная проблема :)